# Inserting objective-c sample code sections into a working xCode objective-c IOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, self

I am trying to implement an answer to an old question.

Here is that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26725721/1984167

And here are the code sections suggested in that answer:

```
self.name = self.peripheral.name;
[self.peripheral addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
        [self peripheralDidUpdateName:self.peripheral];
        return;
    }
    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
}


- (void)peripheralDidUpdateName:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
    if([peripheral.name isEqualToString:self.name]) return;
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(peripheralDidUpdateName:)]) {
        [self.delegate peripheralDidUpdateName:self];
    }
}
```

I am using xCode 13.2.1 and my project has been operational for years but recently Bluetooth peripheral renaming has been become an issue which I need to solve.

First, I do not know for sure where I need to place the two lines that adds an observer.

I have tried adding the 2 observer creation lines in my ViewContoller.c code:

1. The code section where its global variables are defined
2. In its @interface section
3. In its viewDidLoad

Unfortunately all 3 locations had different compiling errors, none of which I could solve.

After I have help placing those two lines of code it also looks like I will need help concerning errors in the use of the 'self' keyword.

I am a novice objective-c programmer and I do not understand how to implement the 'Self' Keyword as used by this sample code into my project.

I have searched and tried to understand 'Self' Keyword usage so that I can modify the code sample for use in my project but I get lost in the subtleties of when/where and for what purpose 'self' serves.

I think that if someone helps me with 'where to put the two lines that add an observer' and with the 'self' usage issue, I may be able to actually understand how this code can get compiled into my project so I can test it.

Thanks
Dale

Comment: `self`? You never used `self`? You need to create a `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name` first, then, you can add the `self.name = ..` and  `addObserver:` when you did connect with the peripheral?

Comment: Thanks, I was half way there, then I used your comment to get to code that compiles but which I am not sure is doing what I expected.  I will edit my question as I learn more about what this code should do.  Like, should it actually revert a peripheral name to what I renamed it (eg DALE1 which was done after our first Apple device connection) whenever Apple tries to set it back to the first name of 00000 which we advertised on our 1st ever connection to an Apple device.  I am hope that this code prevents the Apple device from ever setting it back to 00000     :)